# NSolve cannot work with MinValue?

Tags: equation-solving, physics

I am trying to solve the following problem: find the smallest value of $b$ such that the inverse of the solution `u[p]` given by `NDSolveValue` is never less than 1.

```
f[b_, v_] := NDSolveValue[{u''[p] + u[p] == 1/(2*(b*v)^2) + 3/2*u[p]^2, 
    u[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0}, u, {p, 0.1, 10}];
```

To do this for a given value of `v`, here 0.2, I have written the following code

```
g[q_] := MinValue[{(1/f[q, 0.2][p]), 10 > p > 0.1}, p];
NSolve[g[q] == 1, q]
```

The function `g[q]` seems to work fine, `g[15]` returns a number (about 7.8), but NSolve gives the following errors:

[image]

How can I take care of these?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
NMinimize[{q, g[q] >= 1, 5 < q < 15}, q, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
(* {9.95406, {q -> 9.95406}} *)
```

Here an alternativ workaround:

```
Normal[Plot[g[q], {q, 0, 20}, MaxRecursion -> 3,MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{1}},MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large]}]] /.Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Text[Style[x, 14]], Offset[{-20, 10}, x]}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you also get a slew of "not a number" and "stiff system expected" errors before Mathematica gives you this plot? Copying your code I indeed get this plot but all the errors that come before the output would make me suspicious. Same for the `NMinimize` approach, code is taking forever to evaluate and generates lots of errors before giving output.

Comment: No I get no errors (version 11.0.1. Windows 64). The calculation NMInimize lasts some time...

Comment: Note that `g` is only meaningfully defined if `q` is given a value, so restrict it via 
    `g[q_?NumericQ] := MinValue[{(1/f[q, 0.2][p]), 10 > p > 0.1}, p]`
Then `FindRoot[g[q] == 1, {q, 10}]` gives a root.